# theorem and subtheorem hierarchical numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems

I want the numbering of claims, subclaims, subsubclaims, etc to be hierarchically numbered. Is there a way to do this without having to make those extra "subclaim" environments? For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[thm]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
this has a long proof. i break it up into smaller claims.
\end{thm}

\begin{claim}
i prove a smaller piece of the theorem. 
this proof makes its own even smaller claims.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}
\end{document}
```

This example produces the following numbering:

> Theorem 1
>
> Claim 1.1
>
> Claim 1.2

Ideally, I would want the numbering to go like:

> Theorem 1
>
> Claim 1.1
>
> Claim 1.1.1

since the last claim "belongs" to the claim before it.

Some of the solutions I've seen accomplish this by making an extra "subtheorems" wrapper environment. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I think that using sub theorems is much easier. In addition, I don't think `claim` hierarchy is really useful

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining a stack of such `levels` is not really easy. I tried to provide this down to six levels, which automatic backup etc. and up/down levelling if needed.

There's an issue with a reusage of the claim environment when `\holdlevelfalse` is used. I'll try to figure out this.

Use the command `\claimhierarchies{claim}{6}{thm}`, meaning six levels, the 'parent' level is `thm`. then.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{chngcntr}%

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newcounter{claimlevel}[thm]

\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[thm]


\ExplSyntaxOn


\newcommand{\claimhierarchies}[3]{%
  \newcounter{#1i}
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1i\endcsname{\bfseries \csname the#3\endcsname.\arabic{#1i}}%
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{1}{#2}{%
    \newcounter{#1\romannumeral##1}[#1\romannumeral\numexpr##1-1]
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1\romannumeral##1\endcsname{\csname the#1\romannumeral\numexpr ##1-1\endcsname.\arabic{#1\romannumeral\numexpr##1}}
  }
}

\seq_new:N \g_claimcounter_stack_seq


\newcommand{\pushcounter}[1]{%
  \seq_gpush:Nn \g_claimcounter_stack_seq {#1}
}  

\newcommand{\popcounter}[1]{%
  \seq_pop:NN \g_claimcounter_stack_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \setcounter{#1}{\l_tmpa_tl}%
} 


\newcommand{\getcounter}[1]{%
  \seq_get:NN \g_claimcounter_stack_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \setcounter{#1}{\l_tmpa_tl}%
} 

\ExplSyntaxOff




\makeatletter

\newif\ifholdlevel
\newif\iflevelup
\newif\ifverbose
\verbosetrue


\newcommand{\levelup}{%
  \ifnum\c@claimlevel > 1
  \addtocounter{claimlevel}{\m@ne}
  \ifverbose
  Level up to Level \Roman{claimlevel}
  \fi
  \leveluptrue
  \fi
}




\AtBeginEnvironment{claim}{%
  \iflevelup
  \csletcs{theclaim}{theclaim\romannumeral\numexpr\c@claimlevel}
  \csletcs{c@claim}{c@claim\romannumeral\c@claimlevel}
  \else
  \ifholdlevel
  \ifverbose
  Hold Level on Level \Roman{claimlevel}
  \fi
  \csletcs{theclaim}{theclaim\romannumeral\numexpr\c@claimlevel}
  \csletcs{c@claim}{c@claim\romannumeral\c@claimlevel}
  \else
  \addtocounter{claimlevel}{1}%
  \ifverbose
  Level down to Level \Roman{claimlevel}
  \fi
  \pushcounter{\number\value{claim}}%
  \csletcs{theclaim}{theclaim\romannumeral\numexpr\c@claimlevel} % 
  \csletcs{c@claim}{c@claim\romannumeral\c@claimlevel}
  \fi
  \fi
}

\makeatother


\claimhierarchies{claim}{6}{thm}


\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
this has a long proof. i break it up into smaller claims.
\end{thm}

\begin{claim}
i prove a smaller piece of the theorem. 
this proof makes its own even smaller claims.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}


\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}


\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}


\holdleveltrue


\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}


\levelup

\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}



\levelup

\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\holdleveltrue

\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\holdlevelfalse
\levelupfalse


\begin{claim}
i prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\expandafter` used inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`? Oh, my! `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I have to change that. It's a quick fix

Answer (score 1):

The `claim` environment accepts an optional argument, default `=`, that's used to climb up or down a level. With `+` you go one level up, with `-` one level down; it's also possible to jump down two or three levels with `--` and `---`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,xparse,etoolbox}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Claim}{Claim}[theorem]
\newtheorem{ClaimI}{Claim}[Claim]
\newtheorem{ClaimII}{Claim}[ClaimI]
\newtheorem{ClaimIII}{Claim}[ClaimII]
\newcounter{claimlevel}[theorem]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{claim}{O{=}}
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {=}  { }
    {+}  { \stepcounter{claimlevel} }
    {-}  { \addtocounter{claimlevel}{-1} }
    {--} { \addtocounter{claimlevel}{-2} }
    {---}{ \addtocounter{claimlevel}{-3} }
   }
  \begin{ Claim \int_to_Roman:n { \value{claimlevel} } }
 }
 {
  \end{ Claim \int_to_Roman:n { \value{claimlevel} } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This has a long proof. I break it up into smaller claims.
\end{theorem}

\begin{claim}
I prove a smaller piece of the theorem. 
This proof makes its own even smaller claims.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[+]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[+]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[-]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[-]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[+]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[-]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}


\begin{theorem}
This has a long proof. I break it up into smaller claims.
\end{theorem}

\begin{claim}
I prove a smaller piece of the theorem. 
This proof makes its own even smaller claims.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[+]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[+]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[--]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[+]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[+]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[--]
I prove a claim made in the previous claim environment.
\end{claim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Providing more than four levels is possible, but, I hope, not needed.